# Is there a sandbox at Philosophy SE or is Meta good enough for that?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've found out at WorldBuilding SE that if I have a very complicated question which needs to be fine tuned but I fail to do so myself, there is a sandbox.

My question is actually more or less a thought experiment, while I consider thought experiments as sort of world building it can be still a philosophical excercise.

How can I ask a [question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions/7474#7474) of this type here?